# Process array starting with second entry?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP and would like to use `foreach` to process entries skipping [0], to process [1], [2], etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `array_slice`

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
foreach (array_slice($array,1) as $value ) {
    echo $value;
}
```

If you don't mind losing first element you can use `array_shift`

```
array_shift($array);
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Output

```
23
```

Comment: I ended up using array_shift after accessing the first array element. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($ar as $value) {
    if ($i > 0) {
        // code here
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: you could even put the "++" after the $i in the if statement and save a whole line of code :)

Comment: `foreach ($ar as $i => $value) {`, but indeed, OP didn't say he has 0..N indexed array

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a variable for this:

```
$firstSkipped = false;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if (!$firstSkipped) {
        $firstSkipped = true;
        continue;
    }
    // code here
}
```

Or you could just use a regular `for` loop, setting the beginning counter to 1:

```
for ($i = 1, $count = count($arr); $i < $count; $i++) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Continue is better because you don't have to nest your working code. It's so much nicer to go to the next iteration of the loop than to indent all the working code because it wasn't skipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the first entry from an array with [array_shift](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

```
$array = array("a","b","c");
array_shift($array);
foreach ($array as $values)
{
    echo $values; //bc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arr = array(0,1,2,3,4,5);

unset($arr[0]);

foreach($arr as $value) {
    echo $value;
    echo "<br />";  
}
```

This would delete first entry from array, so it would not skip as you asked, but anyway you can try this...

Comment: OP didn't say he want to unset it. I think he's trying to skip it just for one foreach().